# How to tell the degree of a polynomial just from graph?

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Received this question today, been thinking about this, here are my current thoughts:

1. From end behavior, one can easily determine if the degree is even or odd
2. Find any points where the derivative is equal to 0, say there are k of those points.
3. The degree will be at least k+1 (if it matches the even/odd we got from step 1), or k+2 (if k+1 doesn't match?).
4. Starting from k+1 or k+2, any additional 2s can be added to the degree which are also possible.

Am I right in this line of thinking? Initially just thought about k+1 and ignored step 1), but noticed that line of thinking does not work for x^3, for example.

Any inputs are appreciated!

Comment: Yeah that seems good. If you only have maxima or minima with $f''(x)\neq 0$, then the degree will be exactly $k+1$. but if you have saddle points / points with higher multiplicity, you may add $2$s to the degree

Comment: This question only makes sense within a certain context that must be assumed by the person asked. I can, sort of, tell whether the polynomial curve is of degree $1$ (line), $2$ (parabola), $3$ (not a line, and look at the end behaviour), $4$ (not a parabola, look at the end behaviour) ... but I don't think any such logic will help me decide if a given polynomial is of degree $752,282,311$ or $752,282,313$. :(

Comment: @LegNaiB This is great, thank you! The way I look at it, can I think about each maxima/minima (when f''x =!0) as counting them once, and each saddle point as counting them *twice*? That way if I count k of them, it seems like the degree would simply be k+1+2n.

Comment: The polynomial function of an odd degree doesn't need to have any maxima or minima and may have only one saddle point. The polynomial function of an even degree doesn't need to have any saddle points and may have only one maximum or minimum. I mean, these are all good heuristics, but there are notable cases when they are useless. Thus my question - is some context assumed there? For example, is $4$ the highest degree that you may encounter?

Comment: @StinkingBishop I understand all your points - no there are not any notable context you are missing here. Hence I mentioned about starting from k+1, any copies of 2 may be added which are also possible. I suppose this can be reduced to a simpler question, from a graph how can we tell the least degree of polynomial that could possible look like it.

Comment: Exactly, you can tell the minimum degree by counting the number of points with $f'(x) = 0$. However, in general it's not easy to determine the multiplicity of such points. Looking at $x^n$, you can barely differentiate $x^{20}$ and $x^{22}$. In that case looking at the graphs of the derivatives of $f$ could help to find out how many times you should count an extremal point.